# UI for enlarging image, showing next image

Tags: gui-design, navigation

I have a website that displays items. Each item can have multiple images, but only shows one at a time, along with the item text. The user can click anywhere on an image to show the next image. You can tap, tap, tap through all the images, while remaining on the item.

I also want to add an enlarge function that shows the image full-size. Tap seems the obvious choice for this. Not sure how to fit it all in? Swipe is for swiping through items.

On tablets, there are thumbnails of each image, but I'm not sure I want to take up that much vertical space on the phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible options:

1. Tapping/clicking anywhere on the image to enlarge and have smaller navigation buttons that allow users to navigate left or right
2. Tapping/clicking anywhere on the image to navigate left or right and have a smaller enlarge button somewhere on the image that allows users to enlarge the image
3. On mobile, consider having a one time only hint text that shows briefly letting the user know they can double-tap to zoom in

Comment: Thanks! If it's OK to fit two types of taps on the same image, then I think I'll go with tapping anywhere (except the corner) to enlarge and then have a corner icon indicating that you can tap there to go through the images. The enlarged image popup will also show the thumbnails.